# Tailwind merge is not working with CSS modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a Next.js project and I'm using Tailwind for styling elements. I use Tailwind's merge feature to solve class precedence issues in my components. However, it seems that Tailwind's merge feature doesn't work properly with CSS modules (I used the Tailwind apply approach).

this is my component

```js
import classes from './styles.module.scss';
import type { FC, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import type { TextProps } from './props';
import {twMerge} from "tailwind-merge";

const Text: FC<PropsWithChildren & TextProps> = ({
    color,
    variant = 'p',
    className,
    children,
}) => {
    const HTMLTAG = variant;
    return (
        <HTMLTAG
            className={twMerge(`${classes[variant]} ${classes[color || '']}`, className)}
        >
            {children}
        </HTMLTAG>
    );
};

export default Text;
```

this is styling file

```js
.h1 {
    @apply text-6xl font-semibold text-text-hover sm:text-2xl;
}

.h2 {
    @apply text-4xl font-semibold text-text-hover sm:text-xl;
}

.h3 {
    @apply text-3xl font-semibold sm:text-base;
}

.h4 {
    @apply text-xl font-semibold;
}

.h5 {
    @apply text-lg font-semibold;
}

.h6 {
    @apply text-base font-semibold;
}

.p,
.span {
    @apply text-base text-text-main;
}

.primary{
    @apply text-primary-main;
}

.text {
    @apply text-text-main;
}
```

this is type of props of this component

```js
export interface TextProps {
    variant?: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p' | 'span';
    color?: 'primary' | 'text';
    className?: string;
}
```

and this is my tailwind config file

```js
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: '#fff',
      transparent:'transparent',
      primary: {
        main: '#FBBF24',
        hover: '#F59E0B',
        light: '#FDE68A',
        pale: '#FFFBEB'
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#8B5CF6',
        hover: '#6D28D9',
        light: '#C4B5FD',
        pale:'#EDE9FE'
      },
      success:{
        main: '#25984E',
        hover: '#166534',
        light: '#DCFCE7',
        pale: '#F0FDF4'
      },
      error: {
        main: '#FCA5A5',
        hover: '#DC2626',
        light: '#FEE2E2',
        pale: '#FEF2F2'
      },
      overlay: '#1E1E1E52',
      text: {
          hover: '#1E293B',
          dark: '#334155',
          main: '#475569',
          light: '#64748B',
          pale: '#94A3B8'
      },
      border: {
          dark: '#CBD5E1',
          light: '#F3F4F6',
          input: '#E2E8F0',
          focused: '#C7D2FE',
          disabled: '#FEE2E2'
      },
      bg: {
          dark: '#F8FAFC',
          light: '#FEFEFE'
      },
    },
    boxShadow:{
      'softSmall': '0px 8px 16px 0px #1111111F',
      'softMedium': '0px 20px 24px 0px #1111111F',
      'softLarge': '0px 32px 64px 0px #1111111F',
      'strokeSmall': '0px 0px 1px 0px #091E424F, 0px 3px 8px 0px #091E4229',
      'strokeMedium': '0px 0px 1px 0px #091E424F, 0px 9px 12px 0px #091E4226',
      'strokeLarge': '0px 0px 1px 0px #091E424F, 0px 14px 18px 0px #091E4226',
      'indigoSmall': '0px 8px 16px 0px #FFF6D3CC',
      'indigoMedium': '0px 20px 24px 0px #FBBF2433',
      'indigoLarge': '0px 32px 64px 0px #FBBF2433'
    },
    screens: {
      xl: { max: "1279px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 1279px) { ... }

      lg: { max: "1023px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 1023px) { ... }

      md: { max: "767px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

      sm: { max: "639px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 639px) { ... }
    },
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      flex: {
        '2': '2 2 0%'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.